# DIV inside DIV - new line in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Very simple HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:green;">WRAP
<div style="float:right;">float2</div>
</div>
```

Results:

- in Chrome, IE8, IE9: the words "WRAP" and "float2" position on the
  same line; both words and the whole line have green BG
- in IE7 only:    word "WRAP" position on 1st line and has green BG;
  word "float2"    position on 2nd line and has white BG

So - what I want: IE7 behavior==IE8/9/Chrome behavior.

Comment: Put the inside div before WRAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to invert the order of your elements, so that IE can float the inner div prior to displaying the text:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:green;">
  <div style="float:right;">float2</div>
  WRAP
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:green;">WRAP<div class="floater" style="float:right;">float2</div></div>
```

(remove spaces and line breaks maybe it will help ;)

Comment: Of course, it will NOT help. And code from my start message was divided on 3 lines for stackoverflow only, real code occupy exactly 1 line.

Comment: hmm sorry then, ie7 is buggy and it's frequent bug. maybe try adding clearfix after floated div?